# memory leak with work pool in multithreading

Tags: c++, multithreading, memory-leaks

After adding a queue for a work pool, in which i put the jobs and get them with a unique_lock, i get memory leak errors, but i can't find where i am missing to delete.
Simple logic: i got a farm, it split the work, give them to threads, threads do the computation and push into the queue the results, then the emitter node split the job if needed and send it to the threads again.

I give you the actual code and i also post the error of -fsanitize=addres, anyway the  code is runnable and you can try with your best profiling tool.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <ff/ff.hpp>
#include <ff/pipeline.hpp>
#include <ff/farm.hpp>
#include <mutex>
#include <atomic>
#include <list>
#include <array>
#include <math.h>

#define UNASSIGNED 0
#define N 9
#define ERROR_PAIR std::make_pair(-1, -1)

using namespace std;
using namespace ff;

atomic<bool> solutionFound{false};
mutex mtx;

// Declaration for a tree node
struct Node {
    array<unsigned char, N * N> grid;
    vector<Node *> child;
};

vector<vector<Node *>> queueWork(0, vector<Node *>(0));

// Utility function to create a new tree node
Node *newNode(const array<unsigned char, N * N> &newGrid) {
    Node *temp = new Node;
    temp->grid = newGrid;
    return temp;
}

void printGrid(const array<unsigned char, N * N> &grid) {
    for (int row = 0; row < N; row++) {
        if (row == 3 || row == 6) {
            cout << "---------------------" << endl;
        }
        for (int col = 0; col < N; col++) {
            if (col == 3 || col == 6) {
                cout << "| ";
            }
            cout << (int)grid[row + col * N] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}

bool canInsert(const int &val, const int &row_, const int &col_,
               const array<unsigned char, N * N> &grid) {
    // Check column
    for (int row = 0; row < N; row++) {
        if (grid[row + col_ * N] == val) return false;
    }
    // check row
    for (int col = 0; col < N; col++) {
        if (grid[row_ + col * N] == val) return false;
    }
    // check box
    for (int row = 0; row < N; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < N; col++) {
            if (row / 3 == row_ / 3 &&
                col / 3 == col_ / 3) {  // they are in the same square 3x3
                if ((grid[row + col * N] == val)) return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}

// vector<vector<int>> gridTest(9, vector<int>(9,0)); il vettore deve essere
// inizializzato, cosi. n = how many numbers you want to initialize the matrix
// with
void generateMatrix(const int &seed, const int &n,
                    array<unsigned char, N * N> &grid) {
    srand(seed);
    int i = 0;
    while (i < n) {
        int row = rand() % 9;
        int col = rand() % 9;
        int val = rand() % 9 + 1;
        if (grid[row + col * N] == UNASSIGNED &&
            canInsert(val, row, col, grid)) {
            grid[row + col * N] = val;
            i++;
        }
    }
    return;
}

bool isSolution(
    const array<unsigned char, N * N> &grid)  // check if the sudoku is solved
{
    char row_[9][N + 1] = {0};
    char column_[9][N + 1] = {0};
    char box[3][3][N + 1] = {0};
    for (int row = 0; row < N; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < N; col++) {
            // mark the element in row column and box
            row_[row][grid[row + col * N]] += 1;
            column_[col][grid[row + col * N]] += 1;
            box[row / 3][col / 3][grid[row + col * N]] += 1;

            // if an element is already
            // present in the hashmap
            if (box[row / 3][col / 3][grid[row + col * N]] > 1 ||
                column_[col][grid[row + col * N]] > 1 ||
                row_[row][grid[row + col * N]] > 1)
                return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

pair<int, int> findCell(const array<unsigned char, N * N> &grid) {
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
            if (grid[i + j * N] == UNASSIGNED) {
                return make_pair(i, j);
            }
        }
    }
    return ERROR_PAIR;
}

void addChoices(list<array<unsigned char, N * N>> &choices, Node &node) {
    while (!choices.empty()) {
        node.child.push_back(newNode(choices.front()));
        choices.pop_front();
    }
    return;
}

list<array<unsigned char, N * N>> getChoices(
    const int &row, const int &col, const array<unsigned char, N * N> &grid) {
    list<array<unsigned char, N * N>> choices;
    for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
        if (canInsert(i, row, col, grid)) {
            array<unsigned char, N *N> tmpGrid = grid;
            tmpGrid[row + col * N] = i;
            choices.push_back(move(tmpGrid));
        }
    }
    return choices;
}



// Compute one step of computation for each node in input, and put all the
// childreen in the task vector.
void solveOneStep(vector<Node *> &nodes, vector<Node *> &tasks) {
    // std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(2000));
    // std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(100));
    if (solutionFound) {
        for (Node *&t : nodes) {
            delete t;
        }
        return;
    }
    for (Node *&n : nodes) {
        if (findCell(n->grid) != ERROR_PAIR) {
            pair<int, int> freeCell = findCell(n->grid);
            list<array<unsigned char, N *N>> choices =
                getChoices(freeCell.first, freeCell.second, n->grid);
            if (choices.empty()) {
                delete n;
                continue;
            }
            addChoices(choices, *n);
            for (Node *&n : n->child) { //Store all the children in tasks
                tasks.push_back(n);
            }
            delete n;
            continue;
        } else if (isSolution(n->grid)) {
            if (!solutionFound.load()) {
                solutionFound.store(true);
                printGrid(n->grid);
                cout << "That's the first solution found !" << endl;
            }
            delete n;
            return;
        }
    }
}

//Start the computation sequentially, until we have enough works to start all the threads togheter
vector<Node *> findChunks(Node *root, const int &nw) {
    vector<Node *> tasks;
    vector<Node *> nodes;
    nodes.push_back(root);
    while ((int)tasks.size() < nw && !solutionFound) {
        tasks.clear();
        solveOneStep(nodes, tasks);
        if (tasks.empty()) {
            vector<Node *> error;
            cout << "errore" << endl;
            return error;
        }
        nodes = tasks;
    }
    return tasks;
}

//Assign each part of the work to each worker
vector<vector<Node *>> splitChunks(vector<Node *> &tasks, int nw) {
    int freeWorker = nw;
    vector<vector<Node *>> works(nw, vector<Node *>());
    for (int i = 0; i < nw; i++) {
        int limit = 0;
        i == nw - 1 ? limit = tasks.size()
                    : limit = ceil(tasks.size() / double(freeWorker));
        for (int j = 0; j < limit; j++) {
            works[i].push_back(tasks.back());
            tasks.pop_back();
        }
        freeWorker--;
    }
    return works;
}



vector<Node *> solveTest(vector<Node *> &nodes) {
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(10));
    vector<Node *> results;
    if (solutionFound) {
        for (Node *&t : nodes) {
            delete t;
        }
        return results;
    }
    for (Node *&n : nodes) {
        if (findCell(n->grid) != ERROR_PAIR) {     //There is an empty cell 
            pair<int, int> freeCell = findCell(n->grid);
            list<array<unsigned char, N *N>> choices =
                getChoices(freeCell.first, freeCell.second, n->grid);
            if (choices.empty()) {
                delete n;
                continue;
            }
            addChoices(choices, *n);    //Update the tree
            for (Node *&child : n->child) {
                results.push_back(child);
            };
            delete n;
            continue;
        } else if (isSolution(n->grid) && !solutionFound.load()) {  //Grid is full, check for a solution
            solutionFound = true;
            printGrid(n->grid);
            cout << "That's the first solution found !" << endl;
            delete n;
            return results;
        } else {    //Grid full but it's not a solution
            delete n;
            continue;
        }
    }
    return results;
}

//Get a work from the queue
vector<Node *> getWork() {
    unique_lock<mutex> lck(mtx);
    auto tmp = queueWork.back();
    queueWork.pop_back();
    lck.unlock();
    return tmp;
}

//Put a work in the queue
void pushWork(vector<Node *> &work) {
    unique_lock<mutex> lck(mtx);
    queueWork.push_back(work);
    lck.unlock();
    return;
}


struct firstThirdStage : ff_node_t<vector<Node *>> {
    firstThirdStage(Node *root, const int nw) : root(root), nw(nw) {}
    vector<Node *> *svc(vector<Node *> *task) {
        if (task == nullptr) {      
            vector<Node *> tasks = findChunks(root, nw);
            if (tasks.empty() && !solutionFound) { //No more moves to do, no solution.
                cout << "This sudoku is unsolvable!" << endl;
                delete task;
                return EOS;
            }
            vector<vector<Node *>> works = splitChunks(tasks, nw);
            for (size_t i = 0; i < works.size(); ++i) {
                ff_send_out(new vector<Node *>(works[i]));
            }
            delete task;
            return GO_ON;
        }
        //cout << threadSus << endl;
        if (solutionFound.load()) {  //After the first iteration
            delete task;
            return EOS;
        } else {
            if (!queueWork.empty()) {
                vector<Node *> tmp;
                tmp = getWork();
                ff_send_out(new vector<Node *>(tmp));
                delete task;
                return GO_ON;
            } else 
                if (++threadSus == nw) {
                cout << "This sudoku is unsolvable!" << endl;
                delete task;
                return EOS;
            }
        }
        delete task;
        return GO_ON;
    }
    void svc_end() {
        cout << "Done !" << endl;
        }

    Node *root;
    const int nw;
    int threadSus = 0;  //Threads suspended
};

 struct secondStage : ff_node_t<vector<Node *>> {
    vector<Node *> *svc(vector<Node *> *task) {
        vector<Node *> &t = *task;
        vector<Node *> res = solveTest(t);
        if (!res.empty()) {
            pushWork(res);
        } else { 
            for (auto &t : res){
                delete t;
            }
        }
        return task;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point t1 =
        chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    array<unsigned char, N *N> grid = {
        3, 0, 6, 5, 0, 8, 4, 0, 0, 5, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 7,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 1, 0, 0, 3, 0, 1, 0, 0, 8, 0, 9, 0, 0, 8, 6, 3,
        0, 0, 5, 0, 5, 0, 0, 9, 0, 6, 0, 0, 1, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 5, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 4, 0, 0, 5, 2, 0, 6, 3, 0, 0};

    array<unsigned char, N *N> testGrid2 = {
        0, 0, 0, 5, 7, 8, 4, 9, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 3, 4, 7, 6, 8, 0, 0, 0,
        6, 2, 9, 5, 3, 1, 2, 6, 3, 0, 1, 5, 9, 8, 7, 9, 7, 4, 8, 6, 0,
        1, 2, 5, 8, 5, 1, 7, 9, 2, 6, 4, 3, 1, 3, 8, 0, 4, 7, 2, 0, 6,
        6, 9, 2, 3, 5, 1, 8, 7, 4, 7, 4, 5, 0, 8, 6, 3, 1, 0};

    if (argc < 2) {
        std::cerr << "use: " << argv[0] << " nworkers\n";
        return -1;
    }

    array<unsigned char, N *N> testGrid = {0};
    generateMatrix(12,20, testGrid);
    Node *root = newNode(testGrid);

    const size_t nworkers = std::stol(argv[1]);
    firstThirdStage firstthird(root, nworkers);

    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<ff_node>> W;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < nworkers; ++i)
        W.push_back(make_unique<secondStage>());

    ff_Farm<vector<Node *>> farm(std::move(W), firstthird);
    farm.remove_collector();  // needed because the collector is present by
                              // default in the ff_Farm
    farm.wrap_around();       // this call creates feedbacks from Workers to the
                              // Emitter
    // farm.set_scheduling_ondemand(); // optional

    ffTime(START_TIME);
    if (farm.run_and_wait_end() < 0) {
        error("running farm");
        return -1;
    }
    ffTime(STOP_TIME);
    std::cout << "Time: " << ffTime(GET_TIME) << "\n";

    chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point t2 =
        chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    chrono::duration<double> time_span =
        chrono::duration_cast<chrono::duration<double>>(t2 - t1);
    std::cout << "It took me " << time_span.count() << " seconds." << endl;
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: Please read [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h)

Comment: I also suggest you take some time to refresh how to create a [mcve], with emphasis on the *minimal* part. And of course how to use different debugging techniques, like scaling back the code you have until the problem disappears, then re-add code until it comes back again (making it easier to pinpoint the location of the problem). Or for memory leaks or other memory errors, use tools such as [Valgrind](https://www.valgrind.org).

Comment: And lastly a general tip: Don't write large programs all at once without testing. Start with a empty `main` function, then add a *little* piece of code at a time, building with extra warning enabled (and treated as errors) and testing before going on to the next little piece.

Comment: If you replace your `Node *` pointers with `std::unique_ptr<Node *>` or `std::shared_ptr<Node *>` then you can get rid of all of your `delete node;` calls and your memory leak, since the smart-pointer classes will take care of deleting your `Node` objects for you at the appropriate times.

Comment: Nit pick, but since the OP may not be familar with smart pointers it's `std::unique_ptr<Node>` and `std::shared_ptr<Node>`

Answer (score 1):

At least one cause of a leak is found using https://github.com/vmware/chap (free open source) as follows:

Gather a live core of your program just before it returns from main (for example, by using gdb to set a breakpoint there, then using the "generate" command from gdb to generate a core.

Open the core from chap and do the following from the chap prompt:

```
chap> count leaked
699 allocations use 0x147a8 (83,880) bytes.
```

That shows you that there are 699 leaked allocations.

```
chap> count unreferenced
692 allocations use 0x14460 (83,040) bytes.
```

That shows you that of the leaked allocations, all but 7 of those allocations are not referenced by any other leaked allocations.

```
chap> count unreferenced /extend ~>
699 allocations use 0x147a8 (83,880) bytes.
```

That shows you that all the leaked allocations can be reached from those unreferenced allocations, so if we understand the unreferenced allocations we understand the whole leak.

```
chap> summarize unreferenced
Unrecognized allocations have 692 instances taking 0x14460(83,040) bytes.
   Unrecognized allocations of size 0x78 have 692 instances taking 0x14460(83,040) bytes.
692 allocations use 0x14460 (83,040) bytes.
```

That shows you that the unreferenced allocations are all size 0x78.

```
chap> redirect on
```

That says that the output of any subsequent commands should be redirected to files until the next "redirect off" command.

```
chap> show unreferenced
Wrote results to core.21080.show_unreferenced
```

That command shows all the unreferenced allocations and, since redirect was on, that output went to the specified file.

If we look in that output file we see that all the allocations look like this:

```
Used allocation at 7f0f74009870 of size 78
 0:  806070304010209  108060503040705  109020508060902  509060308030407
20:  702010501070204  907040403090608  502060508020103  108010309040607
40:  206050307080409  904050201080603                7                0
60:                0                0               80
```

By inspection of the code, each of these objects is a Node, taking 0x58 bytes for the 9*9 std::array at offset 0 followed by 0x18 bytes for the vector header at offset 0x58, which in the node shows here has all 0 because the vector is empty and so does not need a buffer.  The other thing you can see in this node is that it is for a fully filled in grid, because the first 81 bytes are all non-zero.

The above information is sufficient to determine that at least one cause of a leak is in solveOneStep, where it mis-handles the case where the grid is fully filled in but is not a solution, because in that case it simply forgets about n.

I'll leave finding any other causes of this leak to you, keeping in mind that all the leaked objects are for fully filled in grids, but not necessary solutions.

Comment: thank you man for the help, are you sure that all the leaked object are full-grids?

Comment: I am, but you can always download and compile chap and repeat the steps I have shown here.  It will also be desirable to have chap available for when you check your solution.

Comment: I guess it would be more appropriate for me to say that all the leaked objects I saw reported by chap contained full grids.  The way chap is designed, it can fail to report some leaked objects, because it intentionally errs on the side of avoiding false leaks.

Comment: Note also that if you do "show anchored /size 78" at the end of the test, you will see a huge number of Node instances that are not considered leaked because they are still reachable from stack or static memory or registers by a chain of one or more allocated objects:

Answer (score 0):

Well the problem starts with you having to use deletes at all, using std::unique_ptr would have solved the problem for you.

Seems your forgetting to delete tmp?

```
        if (!queueWork.empty()) {
            vector<Node *> tmp;
            tmp = getWork(); <--- bug part 1, tmp is never deleted
            ff_send_out(new vector<Node *>(tmp));
            delete task; <--- bug part 2 what is deleted here???
            return GO_ON;
        } else 
            if (++threadSus == nw) {
            cout << "This sudoku is unsolvable!" << endl;
            delete task;
            return EOS;
        }
```